# Regular expression with groups repetition

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a regex with Python, and I'm facing this problem.
My regex is the following :
`:(\s+)"[^:"]*?([^"]:)?[^:"]*?"[^:"]*?([^"]:)?[^:"]*?"([,}]\s*)`
My goal is to capture text like this :

1. `: "Some : text " and : another",`
2. `: "Some " text",`
3. `: "Some text : and, repeating : one " and : another",`

The above regex works well with the first two texts.

But now, I'm trying to capture the third text with regex like this but it doesn't work at all.
`:(\s+)"([^:"]*?([^"]:)?[^:"]*?)*"([^:"]*?([^"]:)?[^:"]*?)*"([,}]\s*)`

Can anyone give me help, please ?

Comment: The business of your objective is not defined.  It should not be identfied from your regex that doesn't work. Please clarify your business and also define more example. As in what matches and what doesn't!

Comment: It is used to valide a JSON text. The goal is to replace some double quote inside a JSON text value with simple quote.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `^:[\s\S]+?,$`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/GSjMk8/2

Matches every line which start with `:` and ends with `,`

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution after some days of research :).
I just need to allow colons to be matched by replacing this `[^:"]` with this `[^"]`. And that works well.
So the entire regex looks like this if someone is facing the same problem:
`:(\s+)"([^"]*?(:?[^"]:)?[^:]*?)"([^:"]*?(:?[^"]:)?[^:"]*?)"([,}]\s*)`